# Table inside table using ng-show in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-material

I have a table in which after clicking on a row I want to show new child table just after the row I clicked. I am calling new api on row click so I have to show it in new table just after the row clicked. see the snapshot[image]

After clicking on first row the new table is showing like 1, ABC_1, DEF
Here is code for template

```
<table md-table class="md-primary md-data-table">
   <thead md-head md-order="vm.query.order">
   <tr md-row>
       <th md-column><span>S. No.</span></th>
       <th md-column><span>Project Name</span></th>
       <th md-column><span>Deadline</span></th>
   </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody md-body>
   <tr md-row ng-click="vm.ShowDetailed($index)" ng-repeat="project in vm.projects | limitTo : vm.query.limit : (vm.query.page-1)*vm.query.limit">
      <td md-cell>{{($index+1)+(vm.query.page-1)*vm.query.limit}}</td>
      <td md-cell>{{project.fields.project_name}}</td>
      <td md-cell>{{project.fields.end_date}}</td>
      <table md-table ng-show="vm.detailedShow[$index]"> 
         <thead md-head>
            <tr md-row>
            <th md-column><span>Project Name</span></th>
            <th md-column><span>District</span></th>
            <th md-column><span>City</span></th>
            </tr>
         </thead>
         <tbody md-body>
            <tr md-row ng-repeat="site in sites">
                <td md-cell>{{site.projectName}}</td>
                <td md-cell>{{site.district}}</td>
                <td md-cell>{{site.city}}</td>
            </tr>
         </tbody md-body>
      </table>
     </tr>
   </tbody>
 </table>
```

Here is the functions for show/hide

```
vm.detailedShow = [];
vm.ShowDetailed = function(index){
   vm.detailedShow[index] = !vm.detailedShow[index];
}
```

The value of vm.detailedShow[$index] is getting true/false on click still I am not able to show the table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first thing is you can't insert `<table>` just like a `<tr>` or `<td>`. But you can insert the table inside a `<td>` tag.

Try the below one.

```
<table md-table class="md-primary md-data-table">
   <thead md-head md-order="vm.query.order">
   <tr md-row>
       <th md-column><span>S. No.</span></th>
       <th md-column><span>Project Name</span></th>
       <th md-column><span>Deadline</span></th>
   </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody md-body>
   <tr md-row ng-click="vm.ShowDetailed($index)" ng-repeat-start="project in vm.projects | limitTo : vm.query.limit : (vm.query.page-1)*vm.query.limit">
      <td md-cell>{{($index+1)+(vm.query.page-1)*vm.query.limit}}</td>
      <td md-cell>{{project.fields.project_name}}</td>
      <td md-cell>{{project.fields.end_date}}</td>
   </tr>
   <tr ng-show="vm.detailedShow[$index]" ng-repeat-end>
      <td> </td>
      <td colspan="2"> 
           <table md-table ng-show="vm.detailedShow[$index]"> 
         <thead md-head>
            <tr md-row>
            <th md-column><span>Project Name</span></th>
            <th md-column><span>District</span></th>
            <th md-column><span>City</span></th>
            </tr>
         </thead>
         <tbody md-body>
            <tr md-row ng-repeat="site in sites">
                <td md-cell>{{site.projectName}}</td>
                <td md-cell>{{site.district}}</td>
                <td md-cell>{{site.city}}</td>
            </tr>
         </tbody md-body>
      </table>
      </td>
   </tr>
   </tbody>
 </table>
```

Comment: way to go.. thanks I was missing ng-repeat-start and ng-repeat-end.